# How to freeze brew requirements like pip?

Tags: python, shell, command, installation, homebrew

Is there a way or a special command in brew to freeze the installed packages into a requirements.txt file, just like you can with pip in python? And then to quickly reinstall them all from that file?

Comment: I've wanted to know this as well!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit to answer question w/o version freezing.

```
brew list >brew.txt
<brew.txt xargs brew install
```

--

Homebrew is designed to give you the latest versions of packages. Freezing versions is not its strong point.

There are two features that get you part of the way. `brew list --versions` will print a list of packages with their installed version numbers (separated by spaces, which requires reformatting to be useful. And `brew tap homebrew/versions` gives you access to some old versions of packages.

Unfortunately, the naming scheme does not quite work. For example, I have the `node` package installed, which is currently `5.5.0`. Then I `brew install homebrew/versions/node4-lts`. What ends up in `brew list --versions`?

```
node 5.5.0
node4-lts 4.3.1
```

In short, doing what you're asking would require some scripting (which may or may not exist, but doesn't appear to be built into Homebrew) which tried to map major version numbers to entries in `homebrew/versions` and was able to handle weird cases such as `4 -> node4-lts`. It would be limited to major or in certain cases major and minor versions because that's what `homebrew/versions` has. And it would have to check in `brew info` for each package what the current version is, because the current version is just the package name with no number.

Comment: I actually didn't mean versions - just the list of the packages installed

Comment: Why not just `brew list > stuff.txt` ?

Comment: Oh, yeah. `brew list`

Comment: `pip freeze` gives you versions.

Comment: @idjaw but then how to install from that file?

Comment: @M.R. I don't know if brew supports this. But bash is your friend here: `while read l; do brew install "$l"; done < requirements.txt`. Where requirements will be the result of `brew list > requirements.txt`

Comment: Please also read my answer for a tool that’s designed for this.

Answer (score 21):

Use [Homebrew-bundle](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle); it’s designed for that.

```
# generate a Brewfile
$ brew bundle dump
$ ls
Brewfile

# check everything is installed
$ brew bundle check
The Brewfile's dependencies are satisfied.
```

It works with both local formulae files and a global one for the current user. It allows you to install everything specified in a `Brewfile` (that’s the default you can use whatever name you like) as well as *uninstall* what’s installed but not listed in the file. The file not only list installed formulae but also installed taps (e.g. `homebrew/versions`, `homebrew/php`, etc) and casks (if you use [Homebrew Cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask)).

Comment: I did but got an error on `macOSSierra` see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle/issues/241

Comment: This should be the accepted answer according to op's intent.